# write equivalent mongo query for getting specified output in best way

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Want to know the query which will produce the below result in best way without performing much aggregation stages.

Sample document

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62d6699126d40c3cbca985f7"),
    "name" : "Cafe2",
    "customers" : [
        {
            "name" : "David",
            "foods" : [
                {
                    "name" : "cheese"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "beef"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "Bill",
            "foods" : [
                {
                    "name" : "fish"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "Ram",
            "foods" : [
                {
                    "name" : "cheese"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "beef"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "paneer"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now my requirement is to get those embeded objects from 'foods' array which have name equals to "cheese".

Note :

1. Don't consider that embeded object in 'foods' array if it's name is not equal to
   "cheese".
2. Don't consider that embeded object in 'customers' array if it has an empty 'foods' array field.

Expected output

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62d6699126d40c3cbca985f7"),
    "name" : "Cafe2",
    "customers" : [
        {
            "name" : "David",
            "foods" : [
                {
                    "name" : "cheese"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "Ram",
            "foods" : [
                {
                    "name" : "cheese"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- map on customers
- and replace the foods array, with the filtered array
- filtered array contains only foods with `name = cheese or empty array`
- filter customers to remove those that have empty foods

*you can combine them in 1 stage all, but i think you cant do it shorter way. `$reduce + filter` could work instead of `map+filter+filter`, but reduce and `concat arrays` is slow.

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62d72c5bbefa88fe45d75ecf)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"customers": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$customers",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$this",
             {"foods": 
               {"$filter": 
                 {"input": "$$this.foods",
                  "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this.name", "cheese"]}}}}]}}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"customers": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$customers", "cond": {"$ne": ["$$this.foods", []]}}}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks so much..it works as i expected